# Can not RDP to an Ubuntu machine in Azure

Tags: ubuntu, azure, rdp, azure-virtual-machine

When I create a Windows Server VM on azure I can directly use the connect button to download the RDP profile to access the virtual machine through an RDP session.

However, when I try to do the same with an Ubuntu VM, it doesn’t seem to be working. Do I need to anything in addition for an Ubuntu machine?

Comment: first entry from google search:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-how-to-log-on/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu machines, unlike the Windows ones don’t come with a UI interface installed for the operating system as per the image. Normally, you would use SSH to connect to the machine. However, if your case/scenario requires RDP connection specifically. You can install XRDP using apt-get, and this should give you an endpoint that you can RDP to. Kindly find below the link to [xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/).

Hope this helps!

http://www.xrdp.org/

Answer (score 1):

There is no GUI installed on linux servers.  Use an SSH console to manage your server.